# Re-order list of divs with the mouse using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

This time I come with a big challenge (at least, for me) I want to create a script that allows you to reorder a vertical list of DIV elements (containing other child elements, that should be re-ordered with them).
I cannot use any framework, it must be pure JavaScript. I also cannot use ondrag, ondragover, etc. (not compatible with Opera, as I heard). It must be compatible with all major browsers.

So, what I can use is: **onmousedown, onmouseup, onmousemove**, (and other mouse events like these). I also can detect **sizes** and **positions** of other elements (like the size and position of each DIV). I need a scheme of how would this be done the best way. What do you advice me? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm going to tell you from experience that rolling your own sortable/draggable functionality is going to be a big headache and I *strongly recommend* using a library built for this purpose.

Comment: What in the world is limiting you from a framework like jQuery? It makes tasks like this cake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you wanna simple onclick solution, then i'd made a simple code...
FYI... http://jsfiddle.net/xnXzF/5/

or you want to drag and drom with mouse, then below is the useful link...
http://luke.breuer.com/tutorial/javascript-drag-and-drop-tutorial.aspx